# Convert bytes to string in CameLIGO?

Tags: ligo

I would like to convert a bytes type to a string type.

How can this be done in pure CameLIGO?:

```
let data: bytes = [%bytes "hello"] in
let str: string = ???
```

Thank you,
Edward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using literal bytes i don't think you can do it from the standard lib of Ligo. You need to build your bytes to string function.

If you are using bytes create from a Michelson string you can do:

```
let data: string = "hello" in
let data: bytes = Bytes.pack data in
let str: string = Option.unopt((Bytes.unpack data) : string option)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for posting!